# Create JSON schema from Java class

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using `Gson` to serialize/deserialize java objects to json. I want to display it in `UI`, and needs a schema to make a better description. This will allow me to edit objects and add more data than there actually is.
Can `Gson` provide json schema?
Does any other framework has that capability?

Comment: What would you like to display in UI? I don't really get what's the problem is. `gson` can convert Java-Classes to JSON-format, that's what `gson` does.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Gson library probably does not contain any feature like that but you can try to solve your problem with [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library and [jackson-module-jsonSchema](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema) module. For example, for below classes:

```
class Entity {

    private Long id;
    private List<Profile> profiles;

    // getters/setters
}

class Profile {

    private String name;
    private String value;
    // getters / setters
}
```

this program:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.JsonSchema;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.factories.SchemaFactoryWrapper;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
        mapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(Entity.class, visitor);
        JsonSchema schema = visitor.finalSchema();
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(schema));
    }
}
```

Prints below schema:

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "id" : {
      "type" : "integer"
    },
    "profiles" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "value" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have 2 "type" keys in "id" object! Is it correct? Can you please explain? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure why we have these two types. I have to check. Do you have the similar output in this case? Why did you update my answer? I put schema which I received from `SchemaFactoryWrapper`.

Comment: Then that's a huge mistake!: the JSON Schema standard specify that a single property can have **multiple** types, but not in this way! That's the correct one: *"type": ["number","integer"]*.
Having 2 keys in the same JSON is against every standard! Keys are unique. For more information: http://www.jsonschema.net/

Comment: @MichałZiober i am getting "id" property on top level object .. do you know how to remove that?  This is my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68231913/how-to-remove-bakslash-for-quotes-from-jsonschema-jackson?noredirect=1#comment120591154_68231913

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [JSONschema4-mapper](https://github.com/wodzuu/JSONschema4-mapper) project. With following setup:

```
SchemaMapper schemaMapper = new SchemaMapper();
JSONObject jsonObject = schemaMapper.toJsonSchema4(Entity.class, true);
System.out.println(jsonObject.toString(4));
```

you get following JSON schema for classes mentioned in Michal Ziober's [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17786708/810508):

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "type": "object",
    "definitions": {
        "Profile": {
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {"type": "string"},
                "value": {"type": "string"}
            }
        },
        "long": {
            "maximum": 9223372036854775807,
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": -9223372036854775808
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        "profiles": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {"$ref": "#/definitions/Profile"}
        },
        "id": {"$ref": "#/definitions/long"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Great library, just wish I would work with JDK 7 and not 8 as the baseline. Will keep this in mind should we ever move to JDK8.