# How can I convert a Jackson DTO into a JsonSchema?

Tags: java, jackson, spring-data-rest, jsonschema

I'm trying to mimic Spring Data REST's APIs in cases where SDR isn't a good fit, such as a login or password reset route. I have this DTO

```
public class PasswordCredential implements 
AuthenticationProvider<UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken> {

@Email
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private final String user;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private final CharSequence pass;

@JsonCreator
public PasswordCredential(
    @Nullable @JsonProperty( value = "user", access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY ) String user,
    @Nullable @JsonProperty( value = "pass", access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY ) CharSequence pass
) {
    this.user = user;
    this.pass = pass;
}
```

I would like to convert it to a `JsonSchema` so that I can return it as SDR would. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try gson library?

Comment: ... how would that create jsonschema correctly for a Jackson dto

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with Spring, but we convert DTOs to string using Gson. This is just a test, but you get the idea.

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class NewMain {  

    static public class PasswordCredential {
        private String user;
        private CharSequence pass;
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PasswordCredential pc = new PasswordCredential();
        pc.pass = "password";
        pc.user = "myuser";
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        System.out.println(builder.create().toJson(pc));
    }

}
```

If that's not what you're looking let me know, so I can expand on my answer.

Comment: Not a dto to json "json schema" it's like an xsd for json

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783909/create-json-schema-from-java-class#17786708